# Log OneSignal Push Notification with Firebase Analytics Event

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-analytics, onesignal

So my goal is to log event any push notification that comes up on my app. I'm using Firebase Analytics to log any event and I already know how to use it using :

```
Analytics.logEvent(FirebaseEventName, parameters: [:])
```

But is it possible to log event a push notification? I'm using OneSignal as my Push Notification service.

Comment: in your appDelegate where you receive the notification (userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler) 
add a logEvent to capture the data that you want.

Comment: @AlexBailey I'll try that, I'll inform you if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my answer. But my method **required Backend** to be involved. Which I don't have the answer because I don't handle the Backend part. The following answer is **only just for iOS** part only.

So, the method is using **OneSignal** method, and it's implemented in

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {`

If you're already using OneSignal for iOS you should already write below code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: ONE_SIGNAL_APPID, handleNotificationReceived: { (notification) in
        let additionalData = notification?.payload.additionalData // Get additional data such as custom flaging from backend
        if additionalData != nil { // A condition to avoid crash if additionalData is empty
            let customFlag:String = additionalData!["tipe"] as! String // Get value of the custom flag, in this case mine is "tipe", and store the value to customFlag
            Analytics.logEvent(customFlag, parameters: [:]) // Send Log Event to Firebase
        }
    }, handleNotificationAction: { (result) in

    }, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption: OSNotificationDisplayType.none.rawValue,kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : true])
```

For example, if you print **additionalData** the value should be looking like

```
[AnyHashable("tipe"): inbox]
```

And this value is set/declared in Backend part.